# Querying data from Firebase using multiple filters

Tags: ios, swift, filter, firebase

I have a Firebase array called `products` that contains items like this one:

```
JhMIecX5K47gt0VaoQN: {
    brand: "Esprit"
    category: "Clothes",
    gender: "Boys",
    name: "Pants",
}
```

Is it possible to query products from this array using multiple filters with the Firebase API. For example I might want to filter by `brand` and `category` (all "Pants" by "Esprit"). So far I've tried ordering by child key and then limiting the start and end of this ordering, but I can't figure out how to apply more filters.

I'm using the iOS SDK.

Comment: Firebase can only filter on one property (or value) at a time. If you call multiple `orderBy...` methods in a single query it is supposed to raise an error ti indicate that this is not allowed. Doesn't it do that for you?

Comment: See also [more than one dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432574/framing-firebase-data-in-more-than-one-dimension), [more than one where condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432030/how-to-do-the-following-query-in-firebase-more-than-one-where-condition), and [or queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034092/or-queries-in-firebase/28036032#28036032),

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I do get an error, but I was wondering if I was doing it the wrong way. Shame it's not supported.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If you format your comment as an answer, I would accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done. But I also voted to close this question as a duplicate, which should get picked up at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase can only order/filter on one property (or value) at a time. If you call a `orderBy...` method multiple times in a single query it will raise an error to indicate this is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in Firebase, when you order by a specific key, there is another index involved : push IDs (if you use them) They are almost perfectly ordered chronologically, so you order by field XXX plus Time.

[More details here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html)

In your case, this is not about time, so the only solution is to use additional composite indexes :

```
JhMIecX5K47gt0VaoQN: {
    brand: "Esprit"
    category: "Clothes",
    brandcategoryIndex: "EspritClothes",
    categorybrandIndex: "ClothesEsprit",
    brandnameIndex: "EspritPants",
    namebrandIndex: "PantsEsprit",
    gender: "Boys",
    name: "Pants",
}
```

In the above example, you can query by :

- Category > Brand (and the other way)
- Name > Brand (and the other way)

Just make sure you add those fields to your Firebase index in the rules section, and that you maintain them anytime the items are modified.

(this process of adding a cost of redundant data at the benefit of performance, which is forced by Firebase in this case, is called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization))

Comment: So if you covered all scenarios/indexes would that query all of them? ie. lets say a user can filter out all of these items by selection, could I display the matched results of the brand, category, gender and name as long as I have every scenario covered? Is this really bad practice? I'm currently moving my parse database to Firebase and in Parse I used the query where on 5 different categories.